# Query within a query to obtain certain value with multiple joins in MySQL Select

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables that I have joined in the MySQL query below. All works well EXCEPT I would like the timeadj value with a 1 in column countingtime
 to show from table 'data', not the first timeadj value the query finds.
I know this needs to be a query within a query but I am going around in circles and getting no where.

```
SELECT ttt_entries.tttid, ttt_teams.teamname, data.RacersInTeam, 
ttt_entries.CoffeeClass, SEC_TO_TIME(data.timeadj), 
COUNT(IF(data.division=5,1,NULL)) 'A+', 
COUNT(IF(data.division=10,1,NULL)) A,
COUNT(IF(data.division=20,1,NULL)) B,
COUNT(IF(data.division=30,1,NULL)) C,
COUNT(IF(data.division=40,1,NULL)) D
FROM ttt_entries
INNER JOIN ttt_teams
    ON ttt_entries.tttid = ttt_teams.tttid
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY data.countingtime DESC) as data
    ON ttt_entries.tttid = data.teamid
WHERE ttt_entries.eventDate = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) >4, -5, 2) + DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())) * -1 DAY) -- last Thursday
AND data.wtrlid = '22'
GROUP BY ttt_teams.tttid  
ORDER BY data.timeadj ASC
```

For example.... In Team 1 (data.teamid=1) there are 8 time values in timeadj. In the adjacent column (countingtime) is a value either 1 or 0 but only ever 1x 1 per team.

Table ttt_entries

```
ID   tttid     CoffeeClass
1    23        Mocha
2    52        Espresso
3    6         Frappe
```

Table ttt_teams

```
tttid    Name
6        Team A
23       Team 1
52       Team 2
```

Table 'data'

```
id    wtrlid    teamid   timeadj    countingtime division
1     22        23       3467.123   0            10
2     22        23       3467.125   0            20
3     22        23       3467.432   0            10
4     22        23       3469.000   1            10
5     22        23       3469.112   0            10
6     22        23       3468.987   0            5
```

My code brings back

```
tttid   teamname   RacersInTeam    CoffeeClass    Time      A+  A  B  C  D
23      Team 1     6               Mocha          3467.123  1   4  1  0  0
```

I need it to bring back the same data but a different time:

```
tttid   teamname   RacersInTeam    CoffeeClass    Time      A+  A  B  C  D
23      Team 1     6               Mocha          3469.000  1   4  1  0  0
```

Comment: takes a bit of time to add the tables - sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below way -

```
SELECT ttt_entries.tttid, ttt_teams.teamname, data.RacersInTeam, 
ttt_entries.CoffeeClass, SEC_TO_TIME(max(case when countingtime=1 then data.timeadj end)), 
COUNT(IF(data.division=5,1,NULL)) 'A+', 
COUNT(IF(data.division=10,1,NULL)) A,
COUNT(IF(data.division=20,1,NULL)) B,
COUNT(IF(data.division=30,1,NULL)) C,
COUNT(IF(data.division=40,1,NULL)) D
FROM ttt_entries
INNER JOIN ttt_teams
    ON ttt_entries.tttid = ttt_teams.tttid
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY data.countingtime DESC) as data
    ON ttt_entries.tttid = data.teamid
WHERE ttt_entries.eventDate = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) >4, -5, 2) + DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())) * -1 DAY) -- last Thursday
AND data.wtrlid = '22'
GROUP BY ttt_teams.tttid  
ORDER BY data.timeadj ASC
```

Comment: Thank you! I am glad to see I was at least putting the subquery in the right place but hadn't tried CASE